# How to end script with condition? Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code :

```
function bakePercentageA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Where is the percentage range?
  var range = "B2:D2";
  // Get the corresponding percentage value
  var percentage = ss.getSheetByName("Total").getRange(range).getValues();
  
  // Get the range to put the percentage value in
  var clientSheet = ss.getSheetByName("clientA");
  var lastRow = clientSheet.getLastRow();

  // Bake the value into the range
  clientSheet.getRange(lastRow, 4, 1, 3).setValues(percentage);
}
```

Hi, i have a question. Every time that code is run, it sets the value for sheet `clientA`, in the last row of column 4. Sometimes there is already data in that cell and it will be overwritten. How can be adjusted so that if the last cell is empty then set the value, and if there have a value, the script terminates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
clientSheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).setValue(percentage);
```

#### To:

```
var range = clientSheet.getRange(lastRow, 4);
if (range.isBlank()) {
  range.setValue(percentage);
}
```

- In this modification, when `clientSheet.getRange(lastRow, 4)` is empty, `range.setValue(percentage)` is run.

#### Reference:

- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)

### Added:

I noticed that your question has been changed. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
clientSheet.getRange(lastRow, 4, 1, 3).setValues(percentage);
```

#### To:

```
var range = clientSheet.getRange(lastRow, 4, 1, 3);
if (range.getValues()[0].join("") == "") {
  range.setValues(percentage);
}
```

Comment: @Leti Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
function bakePercentageA() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const range = "B2";
  const percentage = ss.getSheetByName("Total").getRange(range).getValue();
  const clientSheet = ss.getSheetByName("clientA");
  const lastRow = clientSheet.getLastRow();
  if(!clientSheet.getRange(lastRow,4).getValue()=='') {//just checks the to see if the value is null before writing a new value.
    clientSheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).setValue(percentage);
  }
}
```